# How to plot the Poincaré Section? (Duffing Oscillator)

Tags: fortran, numerical-methods, differential-equations

I've written a program that successfully shows a simple limit cycle for the Duffing equation. However, I now need to plot the Poincaré section for this case.

I need to do this by taking snapshots of the Phase-Space diagram at regular time intervals, such that `t*omega = 2*pi*n`. As I have omega set to 1 for this case, this is just when `t = 2*pi*n`. I've attempted this, but am not getting the Poincaré section I expect.

Here's my code:

```
program rungekutta
implicit none
integer, parameter :: dp = selected_real_kind(15,300)
integer :: i, n
real(kind=dp) z, y, t, A, C, D, B, omega, h
open(unit=100, file="rungekutta.dat",status='replace')
n = 0
!constants
omega = 1.0_dp
A = 0.25_dp
B = 1.0_dp
C = 0.1_dp
D = 1.0_dp
y = 0.0_dp
z = 0.0_dp
t = 0.0_dp
do i=1,1000
call rk2(z, y, t, n)
n = n + 1.0_dp
write(100,*) y, z
end do

contains
subroutine rk2(z, y, t, n) !subroutine to implement runge-kutta algorithm
implicit none
integer, parameter :: dp = selected_real_kind(15,300)
integer, intent(inout) :: n
real(kind=dp) :: k1y, k1z, k2y, k2z, y, z, t, pi
pi = 4.0*ATAN(1.0)
h = 0.1_dp
t = n*2*pi
k1y = dydt(y,z,t)*h
k1z = dzdt(y,z,t)*h
k2z = dzdt(y + (0.5_dp*k1y), z + (0.5_dp*k1z), t + (0.5_dp*h))*h
k2y = dydt(y, z +(0.5_dp*k1z), t)*h
y = y + k2y
z = z + k2z
end subroutine

!2nd order ODE split into 2 for coupled Runge-Kutta, useful to define 2 
functions
function dzdt(y,z,t)
real(kind=dp) :: y, z, t, dzdt
dzdt = -A*y**3.0_dp + B*y - C*z + D*sin(omega*t)
end function

function dydt(y,z,t)
real(kind=dp) ::  z, dydt, y, t
dydt = z
end function
end program
```

I have also attached an image of what my Poincaré section looks like:

[image: Poincaré section].

This is y on the x axis vs dydt.

And an image of what I'd expect:[image]

Comment: Please use some indentation in your programs. It is very hard to read. So, what do you expect instead? What does the plot show? Which variables? How should it look like when correct?

Comment: In subroutine rk2, k2y should have the same arguments to dydt as k2z has to dzdt. In function dzdt, you should have -B*y rather than +B*y. But you should rewrite rk2 to take a vector argument y where y(1) = previous y and y(2) = previous z. You then have just one function dydt that returns a vector. This makes coding simpler and avoids the first error alluded to above.

Comment: @VladimirF Thanks, I've edited the question now.

Comment: I have no ides what those dots in the plot mean (eventhough I did use a Poincare section before) There is even no description. Anyway, see the good advice by @user5713492 above.

Comment: @user5713492 I've changed my code to that now, but I'm still getting the exact same Poincaré section.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the current version of your code.

Comment: @LutzL Please do not remove the [tag:fortran] tag from Fortran questions!!! I spend loads of time adding it to questions. It is a lot of work. If you want to remove a tag, remove fortran90, it is not really necessary here. Are you going to remove the python tag from question tagged python-2.7?

Comment: @VladimirF : There were and now are 3 fortran tags of the recommended 4-5 for a language-independent problem with implementing a numerical method. I was trying to remove seemingly unnecessary redundancy, sorry that it was at the wrong end of the specialization.

Answer (score 1):

In your `rk2` routine you perform **one** step of step length `0.1`. Thus the plot is the full trajectory of the solution at that resolution. However the intend seems to be to integrate over a full period length. This would require a loop in that routine.

In other words, what you want is the plot of `(y(n*T), z(n*T))` where `T` is one of the periods of the system, per your code `T=2*p`. What you actually compute is `(y(n*h), z(n*h))` where `h=0.1` is the step size of a single step of RK2.

Also the arguments of `k2y` need to be corrected as per the comment of user5713492

With a corrected integrator you should get something like the following picture:

[image: phase portrait with Poincaré section]

where the red squares are the points at `t=n*2*pi`. The indicated step size by the dots on the solution curve is the same `h=0.1`, the integration is over `t=0..300`.

```
def RK2(f,u,times,subdiv = 1):
     uout = np.zeros((len(times),)+u.shape)
     uout[0] = u;
     for k in range(len(times)-1):
         t = times[k]
         h = (times[k+1]-times[k])/subdiv
         for j in range(subdiv):
            k1 = f(u,t)*h
            k2 = f(u+0.5*k1, t+0.5*h)*h
            u, t = u+k2, t+h
         uout[k+1]=u
     return uout

def plotphase(A,B,C,D):
     def derivs(u,t): y,z = u; return np.array([ z, -A*y**3 + B*y - C*z + D*np.sin(t) ])
     N=60
     u0 = np.array([0.0, 0.0])
     t  = np.arange(0,300,2*np.pi/N); 
     u  = RK2(derivs, u0, t, subdiv = 10)
     plt.plot(u[:-2*N,0],u[:-2*N,1],'.--y', u[-2*N:,0],u[-2*N:,1], '.-b', lw=0.5, ms=2);
     plt.plot(u[::N,0],u[::N,1],'rs', ms=4); plt.grid(); plt.show()

plotphase(0.25, 1.0, 0.1, 1.0)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "integrate over a full period length"? I do not understand.

Comment: See the new middle part. There is a gap between intent and actual implementation.